# difficulty in understanding how pointers work in c

Tags: c, pointers

I am learning c language for over a year now. But I still don't understand how pointers work. Can anyone suggest a good online resource to make concepts clear.

Comment: This seems legit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rxvv9krECNw

Answer (score 0):

There is vast number of sources regarding C pointers. You can google for it. Try to read a few, one of them may just click.

Here just few which I like:

https://boredzo.org/pointers/

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Pointers_and_arrays

https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/C/node10.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/function-pointer-in-c/

Answer (score 0):

If you are clear with your concepts of pointers in one language, it would mean that you are clear in all possible programming languages as it is one of the most fundamental concepts.

1. **Geeks for Geeks** : More reliable source to clear basic concepts

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pointers-in-c-and-c-set-1-introduction-arithmetic-and-array/

2. **Hackerrank** is a good source for practical knowledge

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/c-tutorial-pointer/problem

3. **Tutorials Point** is yet another saviour

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm